# Convert rows based entry to column based in shell

Tags: parsing, shell, data-conversion, reformat

I need your help on a multiple row entry into different columns. And do the same with all the entries in file.

File example (showing 2 entries only, there are many like these):

```
>ABC
*
AGA-AUUCUC-CGGUUCAAUCU
|||
UCUAUAACCGCGCCGAGUUAGU

>ABC
*
AGAUAU-GCUGCAGGCUCAAUUG
||||||
UCUAUAACCGCG-CCGAGUUAGU
```

File format required:

```
>ABC AGA-AUUCUC-CGGUUCAAUCU UCUAUAACCGCGCCGAGUUAGU
>ABC AGAUAU-GCUGCAGGCUCAAUUG UCUAUAACCGCG-CCGAGUUAGU
```

I am able to convert single entry into required format by:

```
tr '\n' '\t' <test3 | awk '{print $1,$3,$5}'
```

But how do I do it with all entries by reading whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with your original `awk` solution.  Try this; I think it's a good combination of readable and effective:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n" } ; { print $1, $3, $5 }' < myfile
```

The idea is to tell awk to treat the blank lines (2 consecutive newlines) as record separators. Then each stanza is treated as a single record, and the whitespace (in this case, single newlines) separates the fields.  This is pretty similar to what you were doing with `tr`, except now awk will run through the whole file processing a stanza at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR%2 { printf "%s%s", $0, (NR+1)%6 ? " " : "\n" }' < test
```

**Explanation:**

You need to know these two things about `awk`:

- the syntax is `condition { commands }`, where `commands` are executied if `condition` is true (non-zero).
- `NR` is the number of the current record (that is, the line number), starting with 1.

Here, the condition is `NR%2`, which is non-zero for odd-numbered lines.  So the command is executed only for odd-numbered lines, which are the ones you want to print.  The even-numbered lines are discarded silently.

The `printf` will print every odd line, followed by either a space or a newline.  Your input repeats every 6 lines, and you want a newline after lines 5, 11, 17, *etc*.  You can add 1 to each of these numbers to make it divisible by 6, so the formula `(NR+1)%6` is 0 for these numbers.

So `(NR+1)%6 ? " " : "\n"` evaluates to a space for lines 1 and 3, and a newline for line 5.  Then it repeats for 7, 9, and 11; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; if($. % 2 == 1) { print $_, ($. % 6 == 5) ? "\n" : "\t" }'
```

That will print the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, etc., lines of the file. After the 5th, 11th, 17th, etc., lines, it will print a newline; after other lines, it will print only a tab.

(Note: this assumes that there's exactly one blank line between successive groups of five lines. If that's *not* the case, then please clarify.)

Comment: Thanks ruakh. I just wrote a script in Python which does exactly the same.